# Multiple tabs validation process in android

Tags: android, tabs, validation

I need to implement a very large form which data is to be sent over the internet in android so I need to split it into several Tabs.

All the tabs have in common a validation process that checks the activities in every tab before the data is sent.

What's the best way to accomplish this ? Is it necessary/mandatory to use an ActivityGroup or do TabHost and TabActivity provide the infrastructure to implement it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally opted for the ViewFlipper component to implement it.